# unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 on cPanel

Tags: python, mysql, django, hosting, cpanel

Getting the following Error

```
 unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied    
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

while installing mysqlclinet on cPanel terminal.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Linux, try adding the `sudo` command before `pip install mysqlclient`

So type in: `sudo pip install mysqlclient`

If you are on windows, right click the Command Prompt icon and select "Run as administrator".

Then run `pip install mysqlclient`

This gives pip the right to download and install files.

https://kb.iu.edu/d/amyi